# SNOWFLAKE Update statement with Join issues

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello having some odd issues where updating the following with a join statement has some issues that i am unsure of how to use correct syntax to solve as I am new to SNOWFLAKE.

```
UPDATE ToTable as t2
set t2.val = r.total
from ToTable as t join  
        (select ID, sum(HiddenCash) + sum(Cash) + sum(income) as total
         from  SourceTable
         group by ID)
r on t.ID= r.ID;
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having?

Answer (score 1):

If we read the doc's on [UPDATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/update.html#examples), there is an example that take this form:

```
update t1
  set number_column = t1.number_column + t2.number_column,
      t1.text_column = 'ASDF'
  from source_table as t2
  where t1.key_column = t2.t1_key and t1.number_column < 10;
```

which can be written with alias's like you have:

```
update to_table as t1
  set number_column = t1.number_column + t2.number_column, 
      t1.text_column = 'ASDF'
  from t2
  where t1.key_column = t2.t1_key and t1.number_column < 10;
```

if we reformat your SQL:

```
UPDATE ToTable as t2
    set val = r.total
    from ToTable as t 
    join  (
        select ID, 
            sum(HiddenCash) + sum(Cash) + sum(income) as total
        from  SourceTable
        group by ID
    ) as r 
        on t.ID= r.ID;
```

you have connected your `t` table to your sub-select results `r` but nether is connected to your updated target `t2`.

Given `t` is the target table, you SQL should drop the meaningless join and join to the real target.

```
UPDATE ToTable as t2
    set val = r.total
    from (
        select ID, 
            sum(HiddenCash) + sum(Cash) + sum(income) as total
        from  SourceTable
        group by ID
    ) as r 
        on t2.ID= r.ID;
```

But then `t2` without a `t` looks a touch funny, so I would drop the `2`

Comment: This is correct thank you for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer